# Pre run SQL query to be used by ASP.net application

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a SQL query which is running on a view and on top has lot of wild card operators, hence taking a lot of time to complete.

The data is consumed by an ASP.net application, is there any way I could pre-run the query once in a day so data is already there when asp.net application needs it and only pass on the parameter to fetch specific records.

Much simplified example would be

```
select * from table
```

Run every day and result stored somewhere and when asp.net passes on the parameter only specific records are fetched like

```
select * from table where field3 = 'something'
```

Comment: How big is the unfiltered data?

Comment: try creating a view with required data and then retrieve data from view.

Comment: nah since the query is already running on the view i dont want to create nested view

Comment: pre run? as in sql server job? it can run once a day on your defined time

Comment: Did my answer work out for you?

Comment: I suggest that you first try and optimise the view

Answer (score 1):

Either use SQLAgent (MSSQL) or equivalent to run a scheduled process that stores the result into a Table like this...

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[MyTemporaryTable]') AND type in (N'U'))
BEGIN
    TRUNCATE TABLE [dbo].[MyTemporaryTable];
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[MyTemporaryTable]
    SELECT * FROM [vwMyTemporaryTable];
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    SELECT * 
    INTO [MyTemporaryTable]
    FROM [vwMyTemporaryTableDataSource];
END
```

or you could store the result in ASP.Net as an Application/Session variable or even a Property in a class that is stored in Application/Session. The Property approach will load the data the first time it is requested, and use memory thereafter.

```
 private MyObjectType _objMyStoredData;
    public MyObjectType MyStoredData
    {
        get
        {
            if (_objMyStoredData == null)
            {
                _objMyStoredData = GetMyData();
            }
            return _objMyStoredData;
        }
    }
```

However, if your source data for this report is only 2,000 rows... I wonder if all this is really necessary. Perhaps increasing the efficiency of the query could solve the problem without delving into pre caching and the downsides that go with it, such as re-using data that could be out of date.

Answer (score 0):

You can use redis. You can run the view once the user logs in. Then fill redis with the view data. Set that object in Session Context of user so that it is accessible on all pages. Then when the user logs out. clean up the redis. By this way user won't go to database everytime for result instead will get the data from redis cache. it's very fast. You can contact me if more help is needed.

you can mark it as answer if you find it helpful.